# Checking memory with Valgrind

Tags: c, linux, memory-leaks, valgrind

i run valgrind to see what errors my program have about problems of memory.
And the output of valgrind is:

```
==31041== 17,736 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 423 of 423
==31041==    at 0x4C2CD7B: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==31041==    by 0x5B0F21F: CRYPTO_malloc (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0)
==31041==    by 0x5874B12: ??? (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0)
==31041==    by 0x5874C68: ??? (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0)
==31041==    by 0x586DE5B: ??? (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0)
==31041==    by 0x4E4FFEA: ??? (in /usr/lib/libpq.so.5.4)
==31041==    by 0x4E40AB5: PQconnectPoll (in /usr/lib/libpq.so.5.4)
==31041==    by 0x4E41F4D: ??? (in /usr/lib/libpq.so.5.4)
==31041==    by 0x4E428FE: PQconnectdb (in /usr/lib/libpq.so.5.4)
==31041==    by 0x401D18: open_connection (database.c:23)
==31041==    by 0x402A78: init (kernel.c:28)
==31041==    by 0x402E9C: main (main.c:22)
```

90% of the errors, is about this!

Someone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Are you opening many database connection handles and forgetting to free them? When using libpq, you should always free the memory used by the pointer returned by `PQconnectdb`, even if a connection to a server did not succeed. To do this, call `PQfinish` with your pointer to `PGconn`.

Comment: Right, but i open one connection, and use in all funciton where i need a connection. How to proceed?